# Returning value from database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was hoping i could get some help please!

I tried to retrieve the id of an item by using the code below

```
     @variable = item.select(:id).last
```

This returns this value instead.. any ideas please?

```
    #item:0x3decf48>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've successfully fetched the item, you just need to call the id method to retrieve the id.

Try this:

```
@variable = item.select(:id).last.id
```